# Can I upload my app from Windows Phone 8 to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Newbiew wp8 dev here.

If I understood correctly, WP8 app store and Windows 8 app store are two different things.
Is it possible to upload my WP8 to windows app store to reach more devices or not?

Please help me understand.

Thanks!
Dvir

Comment: Perhaps.  *Univeral apps* were introduced in VS2013.  A common api, WinRT, with a lot fewer missing pieces in Phone 8.1.  The form factor is still not something you can *really* ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't upload your Windows Phone 8 app to both stores.

**The Windows Phone Store** is for Windows Phone apps only (WP7, WP8, WP8.1)

**The Windows Store** is for tablets, laptops and PCs (Win8, Win8.1)